# Can Nethermind client run a Binance/BSC node?

Tags: bsc, nethermind

Coming from a .NET background, I'm interested in running a BSC node using Nethermind. is it possible?  If so, how would you configure it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible?

Not without a fair amount of work.

When they [forked Geth](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc) they switched the Ethereum Proof of Work consensus mechanism for their own [Proof of Staked Authority](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc#proof-of-staked-authority) consensus, called Parlia (basically to centralise it to 21 validator nodes... )

Looking at the relevant GitHub commit, [adding Parlia](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/commit/2ac4ae8395ef9ec8f150d069308512ab8e43877b) is ~3,000 lines of relatively complex changes and additions.

There are probably various other things just as complex that would also need to be changed.

Client diversity doesn't appear to be too high a priority for the BSC folks, as far as I can tell.